# The rsync command stopped working on a shared hosting - is my suspicion correct?

Tags: rsync

I'm using a "rocket-science" bash script to quickly deploy a Wordpress code to a shared hosting from my local machine. Everything was working till yesterday. Now I'm just involved in a discussion with the hosting administrators trying to suggest that everything is OK on my end.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Running gulp\n"
gulp --production

printf "Running rsync\n"
rsync -vzrP --update ~/Code/Project/wp-content/themes/foo-theme mylogin@shared-hosting-server.com:/home/mylogin/domains/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/ --delete
```

To not be prompted about password all the time, I added my key to `known_hosts` on server's `.ssh` directory. And for months it was working with absolutely no issues. Yesterday I got message that "identification has changed..."

```
Running rsync
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/slick/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/slick/.ssh/known_hosts:7
RSA host key for shared-hosting-server.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]
```

I solved this by removing suggested line no. 7 from `/Users/slick/.ssh/known_hosts` and accepting new key.

but that didn't solve the `rsync` problem.

I always get:

```
bash: rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

Please answer my questions or confirm that my way of understanding is correct.

1) Am I right that the issue is caused by the hosting side and on my end everything is OK?

2) Am I right that rsync has to exist on both ends (my local Mac) and shared hosting as well? According [to this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2041722&s=fd61f61b8c6f6af4cee79e201f84d610&p=12169003#post12169003) - `rsync` needs to be on both ends.

3) I can log into the server on remote with no issues `ssh -l mylogin shared-hosting-server.com` - it doesn't ask for password so my `known_hosts` stuff is setup correctly. On the remote server I typed:

```
rsync
```

got

> -bash: rsync: command not found

and

```
which rsync
```

got

> /usr/bin/which: no rsync in
>   (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/mylogin/bin)

It means that `rsync` does not exist anymore on the hosting or stopped being available to me. Is that the source of the issue?

Thanks for any explanations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rsync` command needs to be installed on both sides of the transfer.

You need to make sure it is installed on your hosted server. That is all.

Comment: +1 from me.  Coupled with the change of ssh keys, it looks a lot like the far end got rebuilt, and whoever did it forgot to include `rsync`.  Once they fix that, things will either be better or we'll have a different problem to look at!

Comment: Hosting confirmed that the fault was on their end. Thanks. PS. I wonder who's such a nice smartass to down-vote my question…